# hiera merging not working

Tags: puppet, hiera

I am trying to implement hiera merging. hier is my hiera.yaml

```
---
:hierarchy:
 - fqdn/%{fqdn}
 - roles/%{role}
 - os/%{osfamily}
 - common
:backends:
 - yaml
# options are native, deep, deeper
:merge_behavior: deeper
:yaml:
 :datadir: /etc/puppet/environments/%{environment}/data
```

then I have:
common.yaml

```
---
classes: 
 - a
 - b
```

and fqdn/some.host.yaml

```
---
classes: 
 - c
 - d
```

running

```
hiera --debug -c /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml classes fqdn=some.host environment=development
["c", "d"]
```

and

```
hiera --debug -c /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml classes fqdn=blablahost environment=development
["a", "b"]
```

so the "blablahost" take a common.yaml and applied "a" and "b" classes.. but fqdn=some.host should apply a,b,c,d.. and not only c,d ... what am I doing wrong?

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To enable [array merging](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/command_line.html#array-merge), you need to add the `--array` option.

```
hiera --array -c /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml classes fqdn=some.host environment=development
```

Comment: @user1908375 if this solution solves your problem please accept it.